# Simplfy row AND column extraction, numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I wish to extract rows and columns from a matrix using a single "fancy" slice, is this possible?

```
m = matrix([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]])
```

My target is

```
matrix([[1, 3],
        [7, 9]])
```

Where I have a list of the items I want

```
d = [0,2]
```

I can achieve the functionality by

```
m[d][:,d]
```

But is there a simpler expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using [`numpy.ix_`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html):

```
m = matrix([[1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]])

d = [0,2]
print m[ix_(d,d)]
```

which will emit:

```
[[1 3]
 [7 9]]
```