# Indexing NumPy 2D array with another 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, scipy

I have something like

```
m = array([[1, 2],
            [4, 5],
            [7, 8],
            [6, 2]])
```

and

```
select = array([0,1,0,0])
```

My target is

```
result = array([1, 5, 7, 6])
```

I tried [_ix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) as I read at [Simplfy row AND column extraction, numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515378/simplfy-row-and-column-extraction-numpy), but this did not result in what I wanted.

p.s. Please change the title of this question if you can think of a more precise one.

Comment: I'd suggest "Filtering 2D array by a list" as a title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using python?

```
result = array([subarray[index] for subarray, index in zip(m, select)])
```

Answer (score 12):

The *numpy* way to do this is by using `np.choose` or fancy indexing/take (see below):

```
m = array([[1, 2],
           [4, 5],
           [7, 8],
           [6, 2]])
select = array([0,1,0,0])

result = np.choose(select, m.T)
```

So there is no need for python loops, or anything, with all the speed advantages numpy gives you. `m.T` is just needed because choose is really more a choise between the two arrays `np.choose(select, (m[:,0], m[:1]))`, but its straight forward to use it like this.

---

Using *fancy indexing*:

```
result = m[np.arange(len(select)), select]
```

And if speed is very important `np.take`, which works on a 1D view (its quite a bit faster for some reason, but maybe not for these tiny arrays):

```
result = m.take(select+np.arange(0, len(select) * m.shape[1], m.shape[1]))
```

Comment: As of this writing (np 1.9.2), np.choose() may have a serious limitation of a maximum of 32 elements. If the longer dimension of m exceeds this value, then I receive a "ValueError: Need between 2 and (32) array objects (inclusive)."

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use ***NP.where*** for indexing tasks of this sort (rather than *NP.ix_*)

What is not mentioned in the OP is whether the result is selected by location (row/col in the source array) or by some condition (e.g., m >= 5). In any event, the code snippet below covers both scenarios.

Three steps:

1. create the ***condition array***;
2. generate an ***index array*** by calling *NP.where*, passing in this
   condition array; and
3. *apply* this index array against the source array

---

```
>>> import numpy as NP

>>> cnd = (m==1) | (m==5) | (m==7) | (m==6)
>>> cnd
  matrix([[ True, False],
          [False,  True],
          [ True, False],
          [ True, False]], dtype=bool)

>>> # generate the index array/matrix 
>>> # by calling NP.where, passing in the condition (cnd)
>>> ndx = NP.where(cnd)
>>> ndx
  (matrix([[0, 1, 2, 3]]), matrix([[0, 1, 0, 0]]))

>>> # now apply it against the source array   
>>> m[ndx]
  matrix([[1, 5, 7, 6]])
```

The argument passed to NP.where, *cnd*, is a boolean array, which in this case, is the result from a single expression comprised of compound conditional expressions (first line above)

If constructing such a value filter doesn't apply to your particular use case, that's fine, you just need to generate the actual boolean matrix (the value of ***cnd***) some other way (or create it directly).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is simplest variant:

```
m[np.arange(4), select]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the title is referring to indexing a **2D** array with another **2D** array, the actual general numpy solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483236/4055338).

In short:
A 2D array of indices of shape (n,m) **with arbitrary large dimension m**, named `inds`, is used to access elements of another 2D array of shape (n,k), named `B`:

```
# array of index offsets to be added to each row of inds
offset = np.arange(0, inds.size, inds.shape[1])

# numpy.take(B, C) "flattens" arrays B and C and selects elements from B based on indices in C
Result = np.take(B, offset[:,np.newaxis]+inds)
```

Another solution, which doesn't use `np.take` and I find more intuitive, is the following:

```
B[np.expand_dims(np.arange(B.shape[0]), -1), inds]
```

The advantage of this syntax is that it can be used both for reading elements from `B` based on `inds` (like `np.take`), as well as for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = array([m[j][0] if i==0 else m[j][1] for i,j in zip(select, range(0, len(m)))])
```