# Numpy: 2D array access with 2D array of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays, one is a matrix of index pairs,

```
a = array([[[0,0],[1,1]],[[2,0],[2,1]]], dtype=int)
```

and another which is a matrix of data to access at these indices

```
b = array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
```

and I want to able to use the indices of a to get the entries of `b`. Just doing:

```
>>> b[a]
```

does not work, as it gives one row of b for each entry in `a`, i.e.

```
array([[[[1,2,3],
         [1,2,3]],

        [[4,5,6],
         [4,5,6]]],


       [[[7,8,9],
         [1,2,3]],

        [[7,8,9],
         [4,5,6]]]])
```

when I would like to use the index pair in the last axis of `a` to give the two indices of `b`:

```
array([[1,5],[7,8]])
```

Is there a clean way of doing this, or do I need to reshape `b` and combine the columns of `a` in a corresponding manner?

In my actual problem `a` has about 5 million entries, and `b` is 100-by-100, I'd like to avoid for loops.

Comment: It looks like you have an extra bracket around `a`.  Does `a = array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,0],[2,1]], dtype=int)` work?

Comment: @JLLagrange it's supposed to be there. `a.shape` should be `(2,2,2)`, or more generally, `(n,m,2)` and the result `(n,m,1)` (=`(n,m)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this works:

```
b[a[:, :, 0],a[:, :, 1]]
```

Gives `array([[1, 5],
       [7, 8]])`.

Answer (score 1):

For this case, this works

```
tmp =  a.reshape(-1,2)
b[tmp[:,0], tmp[:,1]]
```

Comment: need to reshape the result back again though: b.reshape(a.shape[:-1])

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution, whenever you want to use a 2D array of indices of shape (n,m) **with arbitrary large dimension m**, named `inds`, in order to access elements of another 2D array of shape (n,k), named `B`:

```
# array of index offsets to be added to each row of inds
offset = np.arange(0, inds.size, inds.shape[1])

# numpy.take(B, C) "flattens" arrays B and C and selects elements from B based on indices in C
Result = np.take(B, offset[:,np.newaxis]+inds)
```

Another solution, which doesn't use `np.take` and I find more intuitive, is the following:

```
B[np.expand_dims(np.arange(B.shape[0]), -1), inds]
```

The advantage of this syntax is that it can be used both for reading elements from `B` based on `inds` (like `np.take`), as well as for assignment.

You can test this by using, e.g.:

```
B = 1/(np.arange(n*m).reshape(n,-1) + 1)
inds = np.random.randint(0,B.shape[1],(B.shape[0],B.shape[1]))
```