# index image with 2D array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have an image of size `(1080,1920,3)` stored in a numpy array and am trying to index it using an index array of size `(6,2)`. My code is below and it runs, however the output dimensions are `(2,6,3)`, which is not what I expect.

```
A = inPix[np.arange(6), 2darray]
```

This method above is from the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885529/indexing-numpy-2d-array-with-another-2d-array). Can anyone help me understand whats wrong and how I can get a `(6,3)` output array?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if you split the indices into columns, it works.

```
A = inPix[2darray[:,0],2darray[:,1]]
```